# Material Autocomplete only filtering with getOptionLabel field

Tags: javascript, reactjs, autocomplete, material-ui, react-hooks

currently working with Google material-UI autocomplete component. it is only filtering on the "getOptionLabel" option field when I type something on the input field. however, I want the autocomplete to filter on more than one field. as per doc, I can use CreateFilterOptions to add one more field or use match-sorter to make it work.

https://material-ui.com/components/autocomplete/#createfilteroptions-config-filteroptions

```
const filterOptions = createFilterOptions({
  matchFrom: 'start',
  stringify: option => option.title,
});

<Autocomplete filterOptions={filterOptions} />
```

at stringify, I am wondering if I could return the whole object instead of just an `option.title`

please correct me if I am doing something wrong.

Answer (score 10):

First, `multi-additional-filter` seems currently not supported by `createFilterOptions`.

- source of Material-UI Autocomplete [createFilterOptions](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/master/packages/material-ui-lab/src/useAutocomplete/useAutocomplete.js)

```
const filteredOptions = options.filter(option => {
  let candidate = (stringify || getOptionLabel)(option);
  if (ignoreCase) {
    candidate = candidate.toLowerCase();
  }
  if (ignoreAccents) {
    candidate = stripDiacritics(candidate);
  }
  return matchFrom === "start"
    ? candidate.indexOf(input) === 0
    : candidate.indexOf(input) > -1;
});
```

We can see it actually filter the options via attributes, which is coded as only accepting one to compare.

---

#### Solution

As a workaround, if we don't need `matchFrom: 'start'`, we can simply go through it via bind the two string. Notice it does have potential bugs.

```
const filterOptions = createFilterOptions({
  // matchFrom: 'start',
  stringify: (option) => option.title + option.text, // make it one for it
});
```

Try it online: https://stackblitz.com/edit/gwmqss

---

We can also write our own `createFilterOptions` function for Autocomplete props `getOptionLabel` which can support `multi-additional-filter` with those props like `matchFrom: 'start'`.

- document of MUI [Autocomplete props API](https://material-ui.com/api/autocomplete/)

If you think it's a valuable feature, you can start an issue, too.

- new issue for MUI [feature](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/new?template=2.feature.md)

Comment: Thank you for the response, I will raise a new issue for requesting the feature. I like the idea of appending the strings together by skipping "matchFrom" prop. But I have close to 50 fields to be included, match-sorter is working great for me.

Comment: @user3446256 Yeah, and if this helped, kindly upvote would be appreciated :)

Comment: I have already upvoted your comment, but I have less than 15 reputations. It won't appear publicly :(